# How I can set the imageindex for a tab of an TTabSet component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using the [`TTabSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Tabs.TTabSet) component with several tabs . now I want to assign an image to each tab, for this I set the value of the `Images` property to an imagelist and then the tabs appears with an image. The question is How I can set the imageindex for a tab of an TTabSet component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use the [`TTabSet.OnGetImageIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Tabs.TTabSet.OnGetImageIndex) event to assing a particular imageindex to a tab.

check this sample

```
procedure TForm1.TabSet1GetImageIndex(Sender: TObject; TabIndex: Integer;
  var ImageIndex: Integer);
begin
 Case TabIndex of
  0: ImageIndex:=1;
  1: ImageIndex:=7;
  2  ImageIndex:=0;
  3: ImageIndex:=9;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Why no mention of the xe2 bug?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the XE2 [Bug](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/fixing-a-vcl-style-bug-in-the-tpagecontrol-and-ttabcontrol-components/) doesn't affect to the TTabSet componenet, also the OP uses Delphi XE.